How to get reflection definition via reflection in C#
I would like to get the properties and the values of a predicate definition via reflection.
var predicate = new Predicate<class>(o => o.Prop1 == value1 && o.Prop2 == value2);

I found that I can get the class (ignoring that is a keyword) via
var type = predicate.GetType();

var class = type.GetFernicArguments()[0];

Is it possible to get the tuples (name of Prop1, value1), (name of Prop2, value2) from the predicate ?

If you want to peek inside the code o a function (other than just running it) you would need to use an Expression<T> instead of a Predicate<T>.

@Alejandro oh, I see. Your interpretation of the question makes much more sense to me. Given a predicate delegate, how can I analyze the "code" and get the types used in it.
